# If you store something in HBase, can it be accessed directly from HDFS?

Tags: hadoop

I was told HBase is a DB that sits on top of HDFS.

But lets say you are using hadoop after you put some information into HBase.

Can you still access the information with map reduce?

Comment: Hbase is part of the Hadoop ecosystem, so your question  "Can you still access the information with hadoop?" is an obvious yes

Comment: edited to what i think is more accurate.  thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read data of HBase tables either by using map reduce programs or hive queries or pig scripts.

- [Here](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/mapreduce.example.html) is the example for map reduce
- [Here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration) is the example for Hive. Once you create hive table, you can run **select** queries on top of HBase tables which will process data using map reduce.
- You can easily integrate HBase tables even with other Hadoop eco system tools such as Pig.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, HBase is a column oriented database that sits on top of hdfs.

HBase is a database that stores it's data in a distributed filesystem. The filesystem of choice typically is HDFS owing to the tight integration between HBase and HDFS. Having said that, it doesn't mean that HBase can't work on any other filesystem. It's just not proven in production and at scale to work with anything except HDFS.

HBase provides you with the following:

1. Low latency access to small amounts of data from within a large data set. You can access single rows quickly from a billion row table.
2. Flexible data model to work with and data is indexed by the row key.
3. Fast scans across tables.
4. Scale in terms of writes as well as total volume of data.